# for文で得た要素を1列目に並べて保存する方法

Tags: python, python3

以下のプログラムでXを指定したときのYの値を表示するようにしました．そこでこのYの値を1列に並べてcsvファイルに保存しようとしましたがa=np.array(f_CS(xnew))ではiが40の時の要素しか反映されず一列に並べる方法がわかりませんでした．

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
date="1214"
x=np.array([0, 6, 11 , 20, 30, 40])  
y=np.array([92, 105, 114 , 125, 148, 141])  


f_line = interp1d(x, y)
f_CS = interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic')

time_list=np.array([0, 3, 11 , 20, 30, 40])

#for plot
xnew =np.linspace(0, 40, num=50)
plt.plot(x, y, 'o')
plt.plot(xnew, f_CS(xnew), '-')

for i in time_list:
    print('X =  ',i, 'の時の Yの値 = ', str(f_CS(i)))  
a=np.array(f_CS(xnew))
np.savetxt(f"{date}-target",a, delimiter=",")
```

Comment: > a=np.array(f_CS(xnew))ではiが40の時の要素しか反映されず一列に並べる方法がわかりませんでした．　　a=np.array(f_CS(xnew))でaが固定されているように見えます。aの作成方法を見直してはいかがでしょうか？

Comment: コードの変更で, 質問の意図が不明になりました。もしかしてデータを横に並べる方法でしょうか？ それとも別の質問？

Comment: プログラミング初心者なのですいません．データを縦に並べたいです．

Comment: 92,98.486241990199,114.0,124.99999999999999,148.0,141.0を縦1列に並べたいです．

Comment: `np.savetxt(f"{date}-target",a, delimiter=",")` (元のコード)のままでも縦に出力されています。行末にカンマを付けたいということでしょうか？
(もしもそうなら `fmt='%g,'` を付けるだけ)

Comment: ああ、なるほど、`np.savetxt(f'{date}-target', list(map(f_CS, time_list)), fmt='%s')` ですね？

Answer (score 1):

[numpy.savetxt](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) のパラメーター `fname` は, filename or file handle

ファイル名の指定は, (`numpy.savetxt` に限らず大体において)一度きりの使用を目的としているようです。
何回呼び出そうが, 新規にファイル作成・書き込む … ので結果的に最後の書き出ししか残りません。
ファイルハンドルを使う必要があります。

```py
with open(f"{date}-target", 'w') as fp:
    for i in time_list:
        print(f'X = {i:2} の時の Yの値 = {f_CS(i)}')
        a = np.array(f_CS(xnew))
        np.savetxt(fp, [a], delimiter=",")
```

---

追記

50等分ではなく`time_list`に基づいた値, ならば, 次のようにできます

```py
for i in time_list:
    print(f'X = {i:2} の時の Yの値 = {f_CS(i)}')

with open(f"{date}-target", 'w') as fp:
    np.savetxt(fp, f_CS(time_list), fmt='%s')
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます．そのようにやってみたところ保存したファイルがcsvではなかったのですが何が原因なのでしょうか

Comment: CSVは comma-separated values で横項目を','で区切ります。行の終わりは改行。一行に 1項目だとたいてい ','は入りません

Comment: この場合ですとどうなるのでしょうか．np.savetxt("fp", f_CS(time_list), fmt='%s')ではないですよね

Comment: 一行に 1項目で CSV…だと矛盾している。ので, 横並びにして `delimiter=","` によってカンマ付けるか, あるいは行末をカンマで終わらせるか(上記コメント付けたように)
… どのような出力を望んでいるのか？です

Comment: 何らかのツールに CSVを読み込ませる予定なら, そのツールがわかれば判断しやすいかも

Comment: エクセルを用いてcsvファイルとして（日本語間違ってるかもしれません）A列に1行目から順に並べていきたいです．np.savetxt("fp", f_CS(time_list),delimiter="," )やnp.savetxt("fp", f_CS(time_list), fmt='%s'),でも思ったようにできませんでした．

Comment: それは単にファイル拡張子が `.csv`でないからでは？

Comment: おっしゃる通りでした！！ご親切にありがとうございました！

Answer (score 0):

組み込み関数open()を使用してテキストファイルを作成します。

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

date="1214"
x=np.array([0, 6, 11 , 20, 30, 40])  
y=np.array([92, 105, 114 , 125, 148, 141])  


f_line = interp1d(x, y)
f_CS = interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic')

time_list=np.array([0, 3, 11 , 20, 30, 40])

#for plot
xnew =np.linspace(0, 40, num=50)
plt.plot(x, y, 'o')
plt.plot(xnew, f_CS(xnew), '-')

with open(f"{date}-target", 'w') as f:
    for i in time_list:
        print('X =  ',i, 'の時の Yの値 = ', str(f_CS(i))) 
        f.write(str(f_CS(i)) + '\n')
```